# Edit mail.inc to enable SMTP server for sending mail

Tags: drupal

i want to place the following codes into include/mail.inc of Drupal7 so that i can send mail from SourceForge's project web space. Don't ask me to install SMTP Authentication Support, and i don't have access to php.ini , I wonder where should these codes be placed? Thanks in advance!

```
include('Mail.php');

$recipients = array( 'someone@example.com' ); # Can be one or more emails

$headers = array (
    'From' => 'someone@example.com',
    'To' => join(', ', $recipients),
    'Subject' => 'Testing email from project web',
);

$body = "This was sent via php from project web!\n";

$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp',
    array(
        'host' => 'prwebmail',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD', # As set on your project's config page
        #'debug' => true, # uncomment to enable debugging
    ));

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

if this code could success send email without drupal7 (you must make sure it)
then you could do it in three ways:

1. write a drupal 7 module ,copy mail.php into *.module, and make the rest code as a function,that's the way as the handbook of drupal.
2. just copy all of the code to you theme/page.tpl.php , and run it directly , a little dirty
3. hack drupal core , include/mail.inc , just change function drupal_mail_send

Comment: I think the third way is straightforward, i once searched the web and was told to modify drupal_mail_send, but there is no such function available. I will post the content of include/mail.inc below for your reference